# How do I run my Cloud Run service locally?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have the following simple Cloud Run service [from the Python quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy):

`app.py`:

```py
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!\n'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . .

RUN pip install Flask

CMD python app.py
```

How can I run & test this locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to any other `Dockerfile`, you can use this two step command to build your image, and then run it locally:

```
$ docker build -t your_service .
$ docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -e PORT=8080 your_service
```

It's important to specify the `PORT` environment variable here, and ensure that your app uses it appropriately.

Afterwards, your service will be running on http://localhost:8080

Comment: More information on locally building and running can be found in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers#building_locally_and_pushing_using_docker